# Kubernetes pull image error in non-default namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I have a manifest that works fine in a default namespace. The image is cached on my laptop docker registry and I have set the manifest pull policy to `IfNotPresent`.

Everything is working fine but then when I switch to a non-default namespace, the pod cannot come up due to pull error:

```
message: Back-off pulling image "myprivaterepo/myapp:latest"
reason: ImagePullBackOff
```

The image is in my local docker registry with the same path.

Just wonder why it works in a default namespace but in a non-default namespace?

Comment: Could you please describe the pod that returns the `ImagePullBackOff` error and provide that info by editing the question? There might be an issue with permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you need to add the registry in every namespace

look at the docs https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/

`Note: Pods can only reference image pull secrets in their own namespace, so this process needs to be done one time per namespace`